# Cross Compile Windows 64 Bit Assembly on Linux 64 bit

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, cross-compiling

How do you compile and link a 64 bit Windows assembly program in Linux

I already know to run

```
nasm -f win64 generic_assembly.asm -o generic_output
```

But after that I can't just run

```
ld generic_output -o generic_executable.exe
```

and I have tried using GoLink.exe with wine but I am still skeptical as to whether it is actually working

Maybe I could use Mingw-w64 but I have no clue on how that would work

Any help would be appreciated I am mostly just looking for a linker that I can run from linux but otherwise a linker for Windows would also be appreciated.

Comment: You will need a windows cross compiler like MinGW. Your distro may already have a package with it pre-made (you just install it through your package manager). Once you have it installed you can run the _LD_ from the cross compiler - it will likely be called `x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld`, the GCC cross compiler would be called `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` etc. That is the naming convention on my Debian Jessie system.

Comment: Yup, I'd recommend just using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` to link `.obj` files from nasm into executables, in case there's anything non-obvious `ld` arg that's needed.  (use `-static` and/or `-nostdlib` as appropriate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link the objects for 64 bit Windows from Linux install `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`. To do this follow these steps:

- Go to [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/) and download the most recent build.
- Unpack the archive to /opt/mingw64
- Then do `sudo ln -s /opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ /usr/bin/mingw64-g++`

Now you have installed a cross compiler for Windows 64 bit, if you want the 32 bit version do the same but use [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Automated%20Builds/).